# How does Tensorflow construct a graph from your code arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I am trying to understand how Tensorflow is able to accept an expression as an argument and turn it into a graph in Python

I have tried looking at the Tensorflow code base (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py), and maybe I'm just being dense but I can't see how they are doing it from this.

An example might be:

```py
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((100,)))
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((784, 100), -1, 1))
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(100,784))

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

It is the definition of 'h' here that interests me. How does tf/Python facilitate turning matmul + b into 2 operands and an add operation in the graph? I haven't found any declaration for Python that allows `tf.matmul(x, W) + b` to be tokenized and registered as graph elements as I thought I might expect to see in the declaration of tf.nn.relu().

Comment: Well, it's possible to overload the `+` operator so that `a + b` would create some sort of `Add(a, b)` node

Comment: Sounds plausible though I don't see anything like this in the code. I guess I need to dig further. Cheers